# Is it possible to load some JS from external URL in Tizen WebApp?

Tags: samsung-smart-tv, tizen-web-app

Can I load some feature from 3rd source using external URL in Tizen WebApp?

Comment: Do you mean external js library ? or external web page view in your Tizen WebApp?

Comment: I wish to know about both cases...

Comment: You can use iframe for view...and have to allow domain access from config.xml for external library loading.